# Maximum update depth exceeded. React

Tags: reactjs

I have a little problem with my code. When I render my component I've got this error on console  console

> Maximumupdate depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly
> calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React
> limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Below is part of my sample code:

MainComponent:

```
const saveData = (data) => {
    setDataArray(prevState => [...prevState, data]);
  }

return (
    <Fragment>
      {dataArray.map((element, index) => {
        return (<MyComponent data={element} index={index} save={saveData}/>)
      })}
    </Fragment>
)
```

dataArray is an array of objects

MyComponent:

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(props.data);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.save(data);
  }, [data]);

}
```

Is the problem in updating the state up to main component? Or I can't render my child component using map()?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `index` prop?

Comment: Could you try setting a unique `key`prop to `MyComponent` in `MainComponent` ? I think it is because your `MyComponent` is getting unmounted & re-mounted on every render of `MainComponent`. To verify this, you can do `console.log` from an `useEffect` with empty dependency in `MyComponent`

Comment: I tried to add a unique key but still have same problem. I solved my problem by adding to each array id (create temporary now by Math.random() ) and change saveData method in parent component to that:
 
`const saveData = (data) => {
    let array = _.cloneDeep(dataArray);
    const index = _.findIndex(array, {id: data.id});
    array.splice(index, 1, data);

    setDataArray(array);
  }`

I don't know if it correct/elegant way, but it works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice what happens when a child component updates its `data`:

1. It calls `parent.saveData`
2. This triggers a state change in the parent because the data array has changed
3. Because you didn't pass a [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) prop to children, React has no choice but to re-render all children with the updated `data`
4. Each child notices that its data prop has changed. This triggers the `useEffect`, so it also calls `parent.saveData`
5. The process repeats while the original render is still taking replace, etc, etc

##### Solution

1. Pass a key prop to each child. Do not use the index as key, instead use something that reflects the data being passed to the components